# Autocomplete textbox in layered architecture

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox, layered

I want to create an autocomplete `textbox` with my database.

I'm programming my application in a layered architecture (models, DAL, BLL, Presentation).

I've already made a method with an `arraylist` that reads and returns my select command in the database, which is filling (I've tested on a `combobox`).

But when I try to insert in the the `textbox`, nothing happens... it doesn't show the suggestion.

I looked for something in the forum but I just found examples with one layer and, since I'm developing in layers I cannot increment the property `AutoCompleteStringCollection` in my `DAL` to be filled by my select command.

If anyone has any idea how to solve this problem, please explain to me!

Additional information: I'm using `winForm` with C# and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to say that "But when i try to insert in the textbox, nothing happens... it **doesn't** show the sugestion."
well i cannot just code all layers here but can suggest in your DAL create a method which returns **List** and then on your form page provide code like this

```
 txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
 txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
 var autoCompleteCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
 autoCompleteCollection.AddRange(DAL.GetMethod().ToArray());
 textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteCollection;
```

Comment: Well, I try to do that but is calling me an error at the 'AutoCompleteCollection.AddRange()' It's say that cannot convert models to string

Comment: Try to return a List<string> from your DAL and call that in your form, like i mentioned, autoCompleteCollection.AddRange(DAL.GetMethod().ToArray());
DAL.GetMethod() should return a List<string>.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!! 
I used your suggest and had made some little changes and it work just fine to me...

Turns out that the only problem was my method list, once I change it do a **List < String >** things got better. 
For who is wondering, here is how I do it:

DAL LAYER:

```
public List<string> LoadList()
{
List<string> tagsList = new List<string>();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ADados.StringDeConexao))
{
connection.Open();
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
command.CommandText = "SELECT column FROM table";

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
while (reader.Read())
{
if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
tagsList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}
reader.Close();
}
connection.Close();
return tagsList;
}
```

PRESENTATION LAYER (Event TextChanged):

```
PedidoBLL pedido = new PedidoBLL();

txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
AutoCompleteStringCollection popula = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
popula.AddRange(pedido.LoadList().ToArray());
txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = popula;
```

In the BLL Layer i just call and return the DAL method LoadList...